# What is dependencies rebuild behavior?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dependencies, rebuild

I'm faced with the problem of missing dependency file during the rebuild of the solution where one project `A` refers to another `B`. Their build order is correct - `B` project is building before the `A` project.

As I understand when `A` project starts to rebuild, its dependency `B` starts to rebuild again. And sometimes (not always) it leads to the lack of dependency file because it hasn't been rebuilt yet.

I've tried to disable parallel build but it did't help.

Comment: Are you using build or rebuild.  Rebuild should build everything while build will only build the changed projects

Comment: I need to use REbuild. Build goes fine, but for some processes I need rebuild as well and it has some troubles